# Apache Beam: PubsubReader fails with NPE

Tags: apache-beam

I have a a beam pipeline that reads from PubSub and write to BigQuery after applying some transformation. The pipeline fails consistently with a NPE. I am using beam SDK version 0.6.0. Any Idea on what I could be doing wrong? I am trying to run the pipeline with a DirectRunner.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.PubsubUnboundedSource$PubsubReader.ackBatch(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:640)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.PubsubUnboundedSource$PubsubCheckpoint.finalizeCheckpoint(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:313)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.UnboundedReadEvaluatorFactory$UnboundedReadEvaluator.getReader(UnboundedReadEvaluatorFactory.java:174)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.UnboundedReadEvaluatorFactory$UnboundedReadEvaluator.processElement(UnboundedReadEvaluatorFactory.java:127)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformExecutor.processElements(TransformExecutor.java:139)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformExecutor.run(TransformExecutor.java:107)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem exists because of a Bug ([BEAM-1656](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1656)) in the DirectRunner and a precondition within PubsubCheckpoint. The bug in the DirectRunner was fixed in pull request [2237](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/2237), which is merged into the Github master branch, but after 0.6.0 release.

Updating to the 0.7.0 nightly build or building from github HEAD will solve this problem when using the DirectRunner.

To update to the current nightly build you will have to add the following repositories to your project's `pom.xml`. The earliest version of the `beam-runners-direct-java` module containing the fix is `0.7.0-20170316.070901-9`, but not all modules are built with this specific version so you may have to either specify individually compatible versions or use `0.7.0-SNAPSHOT`

```
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>

 <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        <releases>
          <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
      </repository>

    </repositories>
```

Comment: Thanks. Upgrading to 0.7.0-SNAPSHOT seems to resolve that error but introduces another one `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot nackAll on persisting checkpoint at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.core.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:444)` and my gradle configuration is `"org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT",
"org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT","org.apache.beam:beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT","org.apache.beam:beam-runners-direct-java:0.7.0-SNAPSHOT"

Comment: That's a failure caused by the combination of two other issues, [BEAM-1182](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1182) and [BEAM-1655](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1655). Pull request [#2323](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/2323) fixes BEAM-1182, so tonight's nightly build should work as expected.

Comment: The nightly build seems to have fixed the issue. Thank you Thomas.