# Apache Beam PubSub Reader Exceptions

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam

I'm running a Pipeline with a PubSub Source and I'm experiencing some strange exceptions from crashing my Pipeline. I can process a few elements (3-10) just fine and then all of a sudden one of the following two error messages gets thrown. Both don't give me a clue what I might be doing wrong so I removed all of my Transforms and only left the Source in and the problem still exists. I'm posting just some test strings to the PubSub. Any help is appreciated.

Exception 1:

```
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.PubsubUnboundedSource$PubsubReader.ackBatch(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:640)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.PubsubUnboundedSource$PubsubCheckpoint.finalizeCheckpoint(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:313)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.UnboundedReadEvaluatorFactory$UnboundedReadEvaluator.getReader(UnboundedReadEvaluatorFactory.java:174)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.UnboundedReadEvaluatorFactory$UnboundedReadEvaluator.processElement(UnboundedReadEvaluatorFactory.java:127)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformExecutor.processElements(TransformExecutor.java:139)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformExecutor.run(TransformExecutor.java:107)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

Exception 2:

```
[WARNING]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot finalize a restored checkpoint
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:444)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.PubsubUnboundedSource$PubsubCheckpoint.finalizeCheckpoint(PubsubUnboundedSource.java:293)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.UnboundedReadEvaluatorFactory$UnboundedReadEvaluator.finishRead(UnboundedReadEvaluatorFactory.java:205)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.UnboundedReadEvaluatorFactory$UnboundedReadEvaluator.processElement(UnboundedReadEvaluatorFactory.java:142)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformExecutor.processElements(TransformExecutor.java:139)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.TransformExecutor.run(TransformExecutor.java:107)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
```

Basic Code:

```
PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.create(); 
PubsubOptions dataflowOptions = options.as(PubsubOptions.class);
dataflowOptions.setStreaming(true);

Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

p.apply(PubsubIO.<String>read().subscription("my-subscription")
    .withCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())));
```

Execution:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=my.package.SalesTransactions -Dexec.args="--runner BlockingDataflowRunner --project=my-project --tempLocation=gs://my-project/tmp"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem exists because of a Bug ([BEAM-1656](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1656)) in the DirectRunner and a precondition within PubsubCheckpoint.

The answer [Apache Beam: PubsubReader fails with NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984238/apache-beam-pubsubreader-fails-with-npe) contains more information about the bug and how to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated to the latest snapshot and was first hopeful as it didn't happen right away but it seems after some time the NullPointerException from above is still happening.

Comment: There was a bug in PubSub solved by https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/2368 which is getting committed very soon. I apologize for the inconvenience.